# SSRS not recognizing dataset in expression for barcode

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Whenever I use this code

```
=IIf(JPCI_RPT_ReceiptStatusHeaderBLW.RECEIPT_ID_TYPE = "Trailer ID",  
 Code.StringToBarcode({JPCI_RPT_ReceiptStatusHeaderBLW.trailer_id}), 
 Code.StringToBarcode({JPCI_RPT_ReceiptStatusHeaderBLW.receipt_id_type}) & chr(10) &
 Code.StringToBarcode({JPCI_RPT_ReceiptStatusDetailsBLW.item})
```

I get the following error...

> Name 'JPCI_RPT_ReceiptStatusHeaderBLW' is not declared.

It's checking for dataset right? If not, how do I declare it?

Comment: Where in your report are you using this code? The expression builder will help you pick fields or parameters... this isn't a format I've ever seen before.

Comment: Where I set the value for the expression

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your comment. We need more information about your report structure and where you are using this expression to be able to assist.

Comment: You may want to refer to this guide for how to build expressions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/expression-examples-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I notice you asked another similar question earlier... and based on that I think you are showing Crystal Report code, not SSRS code. You need to convert it as per your other question.

Answer (score 0):

The expression is looking for a field name and you're converting something like Crystal Reports to SSRS. In SSRS you refer to a field value with Fields!FieldName.Value.

**Ass**u**me**ing that you have a dataset with necessary fields, your expression would be something like:

```
=IIF(Fields!RECEIPT_ID_TYPE.Value = "Trailer ID",  
    Code.StringToBarcode(Fields!trailer_id.Value), 
    Code.StringToBarcode(Fields!receipt_id_type.Value) & chr(10) &
    Code.StringToBarcode(Fields!item.Value) )
```

You had missed a closing parenthesis as well, but the error check didn't get that far.